# SELECT TOP (1) from DISTINCT values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data from machine PLCs and I am gathering that into SQL database.

I have several machines with "machineID" = 19, 21, 24, 25, .. .etc.

I have thousands of logs from these machines with actual realtime operating data.

I need to write the query to get the last query from each machine.

What I want to perform is something like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT machineID
FROM [moh01dtd].[dbo].[MasterPLC_Data]
ORDER BY machineID;
```

This gives me the results of all machine IDs that are in the table.

Now I want to find the last row for each machine that was written to the table. So something like this:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) * 
FROM [moh01dtd].[dbo].[MasterPLC_Data]
WHERE machineID IN (SELECT DISTINCT machineID
                    FROM [moh01dtd].[dbo].[MasterPLC_Data]);
```

But as expected it is not working. Basically I would need to perform

```
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM [moh01dtd].[dbo].[MasterPLC_Data]
WHERE machineID = <parameter>
and <parameter>
```

is the rows from the

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT machineID
FROM [moh01dtd].[dbo].[MasterPLC_Data]
ORDER BY machineID;
```

Comment: There is, in fact, no point in a `DISTINCT` in a `IN` clause. `1 IN (1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5)` and `1 IN (1,2,3,4,5)` will result in the same result; the `DISTINCT` operator is more likely to lower performance.

Comment: You can use `top(1) with ties .. order by row_number(..)`

Comment: As already mentioned, you need a column in your dataset that tells you which is the most recent. A timestamp? If you don't have a piece of data telling this, there's no way to tell the "most recent"

Comment: I have a timestamp and also ID of the message. ID is PK and iterates every time the data are received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get last value from group by `machineID`
Example:

```sql
with MasterPLC_Data as(
              select id=1,machineID = 1,field1='1',field2='1'
    union all select id=2,machineID = 1,field1='2',field2='2'
    union all select id=3,machineID = 1,field1='3',field2='3'
    union all select id=4,machineID = 2,field1='4',field2='4'
    union all select id=5,machineID = 2,field1='5',field2='5'
    union all select id=6,machineID = 3,field1='4',field2='4'
    union all select id=7,machineID = 3,field1='5',field2='5'
    union all select id=8,machineID = 3,field1='6',field2='6'
)
SELECT m.*
FROM MasterPLC_Data m
        join (select machineID,max_id = max(id)
                  from MasterPLC_Data
                  group by machineID
                   ) t on m.id = t.max_id
```

result

| id | machineID | field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 5 | 5 |
| 8 | 3 | 6 | 6 |

Comment: I have changed the variable names according to my names and it works! Thank you! :)

Comment: @JanBaroš please compare my solution with the one below from slaakso. Maybe he's faster!

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define what the last query means. Do you have an IDENTITY column in the table or a timestamp or something else.

Assuming you have an IDENTITY column, you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY machineID ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
  FROM moh01dtd.dbo.MasterPLC_Data
) AS q 
WHERE rn=1
```